# Unable to Install Core Library for Git on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu-10.04, apt

Based on the Pro Git book by Scott Chacon on page 9, to install Git on Ubuntu we need to have libraries that Git depends on: **curl**, **zlib**, **openssl**, **expat**, and **libioconv**. Thus, I type

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel
```

and I got the error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package curl-devel
```

So has anyone ever met this issue?

I'm using **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS**, and the Git version I'm trying to install is **git-1.7.3**.

Thank you.

Comment: You may have better luck on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: package_name-devel is a .rpm thing :) in .deb land is pretty much -dev

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 I needed: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried simply `sudo apt-get install git-core`? Package managers are designed to resolve dependencies for you, so that you don't have to do it manually. Granted, the version of Git that's in the lucid package repository is 1.7.0, but unless you really need the very latest version, it may be much simpler to just go with the one supported for your release (or update Git later after installing the supported version).

`apt` would go and find the dependencies listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/git-core) for you, and prompt you to have it automatically install them as well.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `libcurl-dev`, though if you just need *a* version of git, `git-core` should be fine.

If you want to build a git source tarball `apt-get build-dep git-core` should install all the development packages you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can install git directly on ubuntu with simply:

```
apt-get install git-core
```

This will take care of all dependencies for you.

If you really want to build it from source, run:

```
apt-get build-deps git-core
```

This will retrieve all dependencies needed to build git (at least, the version of git available in ubuntu) for you.